# Moderator Feature Request - Turn off "more than 10 answers" auto flag

Tags: feature-request

Not of interest to non-moderators but if there was a way to turn off the "more than 10 answers" automatic flagging on worldbuilding that would be great. We get that triggering most days (sometimes multiple times) and just dismiss the flag as our community does an excellent job of flagging any answers that actually need moderating and 10 answers is a common occurrence. (Our average number of answers is 4.7)!

Comment: Or make it modifiable?  allow you to set it at 15 or 20?

Comment: Oh, is *that* why your handled-flags count is so much higher than mine? :-)  (Tim is a few timezones ahead of me, so by the time I visit the site in the morning he and/or Michael have already cleared whatever came in overnight.)

Comment: Part of the reason yes :)

Answer (score 6):

I tend to take the "more than ten answers posted" flag as a "this question is *potentially* too broad, and might warrant a bit of scrutiny" flag. That's what it is intended for. In our case, most often the auto-flagged questions are okay, but I like how the system is pointing out questions which may be at risk. So **personally I'd want to keep that auto-flag right where it is.**

And my flag handling statistics are horrible because aside from basically egregious examples, I prefer to leave flags which the community can handle to the community. We have an active community with many high-reputation members who are doing a good job at handling the review queues; it's rare that I come to the site and see something that really requires *moderator* attention. And that's a good thing. The more we (moderators) can focus on the truly exceptional cases, the more attention we can devote to the few cases that really require moderator intervention. Remember that there are only a few things that a diamond moderator can do which a high-reputation community member cannot. (Migrations, comment flags and custom flags come to mind.)